# Creating a Java Project out of existing sources

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, build

I have some source files for a Java Project (the output is a jar file).

I have several source directories. I have a properties file, I have a manifest file, and an image directory.

I am able to compile all the java sources from the command line & then able to recreate the jar file by adding the class files, manifest, properties file & the image directory.

However, I want to create a Eclipse project out of these for debugging purposes. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You start by creating an empty project of the required type and then copying your sources into the source directory.  Read the online documentation for details, or just jump in and use the project creation wizard that is part of Eclipse.

Comment: @JimGarrison Creating a project and copying files into it is _*not*_ the same thing as "create from existing source." They are two very different things, and I am trying to do the same thing as asked here. It is amazing that information on this is so hard to find.

Comment: Also, why is this excellent question at -1? This is actually the best Google hit I have found so far.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible in almost all the IDEs. Please follow the below steps to achieve this in eclipse.

1. Create a new Project (Or if there's an existing project)
2. In the package explorer, select the project, right-click then properties
3. In the java build path click on source tab
4. click the Link Source button
5. In the linked folder location,paste the path to your source code or select by clicking `Browse`
6. click finish
7. do steps 4 to 6 until all the source folders are added.
8. click ok

This will make your project to use multiple source folder.

Comment: To everyone who is as brain-dead as I am early in the morning: Make sure you are actually clicking on the top level node of your project in the "Project Explorer" pane. I was not seeing any "Java Build Path" because I was clicking on the "src" node within the project and selecting properties from that.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1 : When extracted project was use in eclipse before**

Extract the jar file into a separate folder

and make the folder as a workspace for eclipse.

And open eclipse

right click

import

[image]

And go for next and finish

**Case 2 : When extracted project was not used in eclipse before**

Extract the jar file into a separate folder

Create a new project

Copy the java from extracted folder to new created project with same package in src

Then build the projecct

[image]